# Help with symbol property editor in arcmap

Tags: arcmap, symbology

[image]

I want to create symbols like below With different colouring in a polygon.

How do I do it?

any videos that can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Right click layer in table of contents - Properties - Symbology. Then choose categories and click the symbols to change apperance.

Comment: @BERA Thank you so much, I got it to work :D